# Why can I not set a radio button marked as "disabled"?

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have two radio buttons. One is set by default.

If I try to select the other radio button, I get the following error:

```
in `assert_enabled': object is disabled {:value=>"ORD", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"radio"}
```

As an experiment, if I try to select the button that is already set by default, I get the same error.

Here is the code:

```
def enterShareClass(shareClass)
  @browser.radio(:value, shareClass).set
end
```

and

dp.enterShareClass("ORD")

Comment: Well, if the radio button is disabled, it means it could not be interacted with, right? Could you set the radio button manually?

Comment: Sorry. I intended to mention that I can set either radio button manually.

Comment: Do you have to do something before the radio button becomes enabled?

Comment: Based on your question, I inserted sleep(1) before calling the method. That worked. So, I tried: `code` def enterShareClass(shareClass)     
    while !true
      @browser.radio(:value, shareClass).enabled?
    end
    @browser.radio(:value, shareClass).set
  end `code`